# Как выполнить код, записанный в textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть textarea, пользователь вводит туда, например, `<p> Привет </p>`, нажимает ОК и через js это все выполняется и на странице отображается " Привет ". Я просто "чайник" в этом "санскрите", помогите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#new").html($("#inp").val());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="inp"></textarea><br>
<button>ОК</button><br>
<div id="new"><p>Здесь будет новый текст</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="name" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="append"/>
<script>
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        $('body').append($('textarea[name=\'name\']').val());
    });
</script>
```